# What is a formal word for "go-to"

Tags: word-usage

The definition for "go-to" that I'm interested in is: "Denoting a person or thing that may be relied on or is regularly sought out in a particular situation." (Source: Google's definition) I want a more formal word for this, but I couldn't find synonyms in any of the online dictionaries that had "go-to".

Example sentence:
Jet skis are the go-to watercraft for exhilarating beach entertainment.

What would be a more formal substitute for "go-to" in situations like that? "principal" perhaps? But I feel like "go-to" has a different connotation than "principal".

Comment: One I see quite often (though I won't post as an answer because I'm not 100% sure it has the connotation you're after) is [***de facto***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/de-facto): *​existing in ​fact, ​although ​perhaps not ​intended, ​legal, or ​accepted* - "Jet skis are the de facto watercraft for exhilarating beach entertainment."

Comment: Do you like *favored* or any of its [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/favored)?

Comment: Thanks @JohnClifford, I think de facto does fit really nicely!

Comment: I can post as an answer if you like, though there are others that have been posted since your comment that you might prefer. :)

Comment: "Harmful". (Sorry, just a programmer's joke ;P)

Comment: Not "de facto".  It strongly implies the "only" choice whereas "go to" implies the first choice.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I would say that if some [noun] is your *go-to*, it is your [noun] ***[of choice](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/choice)***:

> to be preferred
>
> *Jet skis are the watercraft **of choice** for exhilarating beach entertainment.*

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: This is my answer _of choice_.

Answer (score 34):

preferred - 1. To choose or be in the habit of choosing as more desirable or as having more value

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prefer

Your sentence becomes: "...Jet skis are the **preferred** watercraft for exhilarating beach entertainment. ..."

Answer (score 14):

I might use "default" to indicate the normal selection from a list of options.

"Canonical" means *most accepted or authoritative* but is used more for ideas than for things.

Your jet ski example suggests that you may be thinking of things, so these suggestions may not suit your requirement.

You may be trying too hard; go-to is fairly acceptable. You could also just say why something would be the go-to choice: Jet skis are the ideal choice for....

Comment: Or, you could simply say that, *Jet skis are the ideal watercraft for exhilarating beach entertainment.* However, that is an opinion, while the "go-to" usage might be seen as an observation of a fact: *I prefer jet skis*; versus, *Many people prefer jet skis*.

Answer (score 10):

If you want a grandiloquent term, perhaps *[quintessential](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/quintessential)*

> Representing the most perfect or typical example of a quality or class

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes I hear the usage

***de facto/de facto standard***

> > SQL Server is the de facto standard server technology in the .NET development field.

---

> > A de facto standard is a custom, convention, product, or system that has achieved a dominant position by public acceptance or market forces (such as early entrance to the market).
> >
> > https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto_standard

It differs from the *de jure standard*, which is something officially endorsed by a central body.

Comment: I don't doubt you have heard it, but 'de facto' (without 'standard') in your first example just sounds wrong to my ears.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yeah, I'm not sure if it's necessarily incorrect or just lazy/shorthand. I've heard de facto and de facto standard. I have edited my post to be more concise.

Answer (score 5):

You could consider ***predominant***.  Both of [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/predominant)'s definitions could be applicable:

> 1:  having superior strength, influence, or authority :  prevailing
>
> 2:  being most frequent or common

Answer (score 3):

You might consider, ***self-evident***

> evident without proof or reasoning
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self%E2%80%93evident)

Alternately, how about ***choice***?

> *adj.* worthy of being chosen; excellent.
>
> [Random House Kennerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/choice)

Answer (score 2):

Everyone has tried to insert a positive connotation that simply isn't there.

A more neutral (and much simpler) word to use is *[usual](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/usual)*.

Answer (score 0):

Overkill: "sine qua non" -- which is more along the lines of the suggested "quintessential"

The meaning (and connotations), however, go well beyond what the original question seems to want...which is more like "most favored tool in the toolbox".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not as formal for fitting as other suggestions but also worth mentioning here: *standby*, often preceded by "old".

> *n.*, **1b**: a favorite or reliable choice or resource ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/standby))

**Usage**: "When seeking watercraft for exhilarating beach entertainment, jet skis are an old standby."